# Total With combination of required fields

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with svl2_name with the combination of Grad, Country, Region with avg Count_emp in other SVL2_Name and Update the Tot_Avg_Grad Column

```
create table GRADE_S1
(
  SVL2_NAME varchar2(29),
  GRADE    NUMBER,
  COUNTRY  VARCHAR2(20),
  REGION   varchar2(20),
  COUNT_EMP NUMBER,
  TOT_AVG_GRAD FLOAT
);

insert into GRADE_S1 values('TY',10,'CANADA','AMERICAS',3,null);
insert into GRADE_S1 values('TY',10,'CHINA','APJC',4,null);
insert into GRADE_S1 values('TY',9,'CHINA','APJC',6,null);
insert into GRADE_S1 values('TY',12,'FRANCE','EMEA',8,null);
insert into GRADE_S1 values('Anuj',10,'CANADA','AMERICAS',4,null);
insert into GRADE_S1 values('Anuj',10,'CHINA','APJC',6,null);
insert into GRADE_S1 values('Anuj',12,'FRANCE','EMEA',2,null);
insert into GRADE_S1 values('kumar',10,'CANADA','AMERICAS',4,null);
insert into GRADE_S1 values('kumar',10,'CHINA','APJC',4,null);
insert into GRADE_S1 values('kumar',9,'CHINA','APJC',6,null);
insert into GRADE_S1 values('kumar',12,'FRANCE','EMEA',6,null);
```

Need a summary table as below.

```
Name Grad Country Region   Count_emp Tot_Avg_Emp
---- ---- ------- -------- --------- -----------
TY     10 CANADA  AMERICAS         3           4
TY     10 CHINA   APJC             4           5
TY      9 CHINA   APJC             6           3
TY     12 FRANCE  EMEA             8           4
```

I am thinking to create procedure like

Step 1:

```sql
--FOR Loop
select * from GRADE_S1 where SVL2_NAME='TY';
```

Step 2:

```sql
select AVG(COUNT_EMP)  INTO V_AVG_EMP
  from GRADE_S1
 where GRAD=INX.GRAD
   AND COUNTRY=INX.COUNTRY
   AND REGION = INX.REGION
   AND SVL2_NAME <> INX.SVL2_NAME
```

Step 3:

```
update GRADE_S1 set
  TOT_AVG_GRAD =V_AVG_EMP
  WHERE SVL2_NAME = INX.SVL2_NAME
    AND GRAD=INX.GRAD
    AND COUNTRY=INX.COUNTRY
    AND REGION = INX.REGION
```

or is there any method...?

Thanks

Comment: Oputput like SVL2_NAME GRADE COUNTRY RETION COUNT TOT_AVG Formula
TY 10 CANADA AMERICAS 3 4 avg(4,4)
TY 10 CHINA APJC 4 5 avg(6,4)
TY 9 CHINA APJC 6 6 avg(6)
TY 12 FRANCE EMEA 8 4 avg(2,6)
Anuj 10 CANADA AMERICAS 4 3.5 
Anuj 10 CHINA APJC 6 4 
Anuj 12 FRANCE EMEA 2 7 
kumar 10 CANADA AMERICAS 4 3.5 
kumar 10 CHINA APJC 4 5 
kumar 9 CHINA APJC 6 6 
kumar 12 FRANCE EMEA 6 5

Comment: What is `INX`? You do not define it in your question.

Comment: Do you just want to update the `TOT_AVG_GRAD` column with the average `COUNT_EMP` with different names and same grad/country/region for every row?

Answer (score 0):

Use a single `MERGE` statement correlating on the `ROWID` pseudo-column and use analytic functions to calculate the average over all the matching rows and, to eliminate the current row from the average, just find the total and subtract the current value and the count and subtract 1:

```sql
MERGE INTO Grade_s1 dst
USING(
  SELECT ROWID AS rid,
         CASE COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY grade, country, region )
         WHEN 1
         THEN NULL -- Avoid division by zero
         ELSE ( SUM(count_emp) OVER ( PARTITION BY grade, country, region ) - count_emp )
              / ( COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY grade, country, region ) - 1 )
         END AS tot_avg_grad
  FROM   grade_s1
) src
ON ( dst.ROWID = src.RID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET tot_avg_grad = src.tot_avg_grad;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   grade_s1;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> SVL2_NAME | GRADE | COUNTRY | REGION   | COUNT_EMP | TOT_AVG_GRAD
> :-------- | ----: | :------ | :------- | --------: | -----------:
> TY        |    10 | CANADA  | AMERICAS |         3 |            4
> TY        |    10 | CHINA   | APJC     |         4 |            5
> TY        |     9 | CHINA   | APJC     |         6 |            6
> TY        |    12 | FRANCE  | EMEA     |         8 |            4
> Anuj      |    10 | CANADA  | AMERICAS |         4 |          3.5
> Anuj      |    10 | CHINA   | APJC     |         6 |            4
> Anuj      |    12 | FRANCE  | EMEA     |         2 |            7
> kumar     |    10 | CANADA  | AMERICAS |         4 |          3.5
> kumar     |    10 | CHINA   | APJC     |         4 |            5
> kumar     |     9 | CHINA   | APJC     |         6 |            6
> kumar     |    12 | FRANCE  | EMEA     |         6 |            5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=85b6fcfae17fa4ddc7618236a8cf205f)*

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
    svl2_name,
    grade,
    country,
    region,
    count_emp,
    (
        SELECT
            AVG(count_emp)
        FROM
            grade_s1 g2
        WHERE
                g2.grade = g1.grade
            AND g2.country = g1.country
            AND g2.region = g1.region
            AND g2.svl2_name <> g1.svl2_name
    ) AS tot_avg_grad
FROM
    grade_s1 g1

Answer (score 0):

This seems like just a window function:

```
select SVL2_NAME, GRADE, COUNTRY, REGION, count_emp,
       avg(count_emp) over (partition by country, region) as Tot_Avg_Emp
from grade_s1;
```

If you want to filter for a particular name, then use a subquery:

```
select g.*
from (select SVL2_NAME, GRADE, COUNTRY, REGION, count_emp,
             avg(count_emp) over (partition by country, region) as Tot_Avg_Emp
      from grade_s1
     ) g
where svl2_name = 'Ty';
```

I don't encourage actually writing the data into the table.  But if you really wanted to, you could use `update` with a correlated subquery:

```
update grade_s1 g
    set Tot_Avg_Emp = (select avg(count_emp)
                       from grade_s1 g2
                       where g2.country = t.country and t2.region = t.region
                      )
    where svl2_name = 'Ty';
```